# Centering an absolute positioned div on a crossed line at all times?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position a div which has an absolute position on every page/screen.

this div is a circle in shape and it needs to be centered aligned with black lines so the center of circle is centered with the center of crossed lines.

I hope that makes sense.

to demonstrate this I've created this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pft3w75y/

when I reduce or increase my browser size, the circle div is not center anymore and I have no idea how to achieve what I am trying to do!

my CSS is this:

```
.circle {
  display: block;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  /*margin: 1em auto;*/
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color:#FFF;
}

.baners{
    width: 50%;
    height: 76vw; 
    border:solid 1px #333;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#FFF;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    position:relative;


}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're after. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pft3w75y/1/?

Comment: @j08691, that's it mate. excellent... that is exactly what I was trying to do!

Comment: OK, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these lines to center the circle div:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
left:100%;
top:100%;
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pft3w75y/1/)**